# How to troubleshoot quota problems on Firebase to BigQuery integraton?

Tags: gcp, firebase

I'm trying to **link my App's Firebase account to a BigQuery sandbox**. It worked a few months ago and stopped when it reached a limit.
Therefore I cleaned all BQ data to give enough space for it to work again (as following image indicates):
[Firebase storage indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXKiu.png)

But its been weeks and it is not sending data anymore. Everyday it register the following error on Cloud Logging:

> Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free storage for
> projects. For more information, see
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

The problem is, the suggested page doesn't give me a clear solution on how to troubleshoot it.

I've checked for other errors on Cloud Logging and nothing.
Also checked any quotas percentage on the following APIs and found nothing (just as the image below):

- BigQuery API; BigQuery Data Transfer API, BigQuery Migration API; BigQuery Storage API; Cloud Storage; Mobile Crash Reporting API.
  [GCP API quota indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCXXc.png)

I've tried:

- Unlinking and linking again my Firebase to BQ integration;
- Deleting and recreating the Datasets on BQ;
- Adding all admin permissions to my Firebase SA on IAM;
- Turning on only the Crashlytics integration of one of my apps (to minimize data input).

Does anyone had this experience before? I've set up this same integration on other apps before (different accounts) and it is working smoothly until this day. I've left with no clue for why this one is so problematic.